# Does the 40K universe have an equivalent of Kevin Feige?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy, games-workshop

Part of the success of the MCU has been the hand of Kevin Feige overseeing the various projects ensuring continuity.

Do Games Workshop/Black Library have a similar role? It certainly feels in recent years that the books have become more in sync, in particular with characters and events in the Horus Hersey books feeding into the more recent (timeline wise) stories, with characters and events being referenced back and forth.

Comment: I don't think GW has ever hinted at any of the steps they use to ensure continuity; even with all the branching out they have done in recent years. With the amount of conflicting information that used to come out of GW they either let stuff slip through on purpose or their fact checking teams did a horrible job! I agree that it does seem like they have all been using the same road map recently and I like to think there is a team checking content before release. Having a job at GW to review and research content before it is released solely to find canon conflicts would be my dream job...

Comment: Hmm, while in general the rule is "write anything as long as it matches the setting", in case of big story arcs that occur in a relatively short time period (Horus Heresy and recently Dark Imperium) writers meet and discuss the general story. I remember that Dan Abnett mentioned that "there was a rumour that on the next GW meeting they will be a discussion about the resurrection of corrupted Sanguinus" and his promise that he will strangle anyone who would dare to propose that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for all of the various works, but at least with the Horus Heresy series with the Black Library, they had an overall editor and the authors themselves would get together to discuss the stories and direction, especially as the series grew to a close and they moved on to the siege of Terra. The authors often talked about this in the 'afterwords' of the various books, but there is an article on the warhammer community site about them gather for the Siege of Terra
https://www.warhammer-community.com/2017/09/20/the-siege-of-terra-dawns/